# Mutually exclusive instances of the same systemd service template

Tags: systemd, services

I am interested if there's a better way to do mutually exclusive intances of the same systemd service template.

Context: I am using SSH tunnels to connect over synergy between my laptop and which ever workstation I am next to. Obviously, only a single tunnel should be running at the same time. If a new tunnel is opened, any still running instance of the older should be closed before hand.

(It's remotely related to [the kind of use cases that this users was having with instances of a VPN service template](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5388) )

[Somehow, `Conflicts=template@.service` rule](/questions/224022/systemd-support-for-toggling-mutually-exclusive-services) doesn't seem to help me, even if systemd correctly removes the current instance from the list of conflicts (`template@foo.service` is automatically removed from the `Conflicts=` list of `template@foo.service` itself), it doesn't seem to achieve the desired result (`template@bar.service` isn't automatically stopped before starting `template@foo.service`).

Currently, it works for me using this horrendous contraption:

```
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sh -c 'systemctl --user stop  $$(systemctl --user list-units %p@\'*\'.service|gawk \'($$3~/^activ/)&&(!($$1~/%I/)){print $$1};\')'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 11111 -N -L24800:localhost:24800 %I
```

This uses `list-units` to get a list of all instances of this service remplate (would return `template@bar.service`, `template@foo.service`), and gawk to filter those which are active and which aren't the current one and only stop those (so starting `template@bar.service` will stop `template@foo.service` before starting).

It works for me, but it's ugly, and I'm sure there's a "*more systemd way*" to do it, I just don't see how.